# How do I change the name of an existing project in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

How to change the name of a project in VS 2008 to something else? I have already created a project and now I want to change its name.

Comment: Give a better title to your question. It is way too generic.

Comment: thanks will take care of it from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename your project:

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Rename".
3. Type in your new name, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To rename the assembly it generates:

1. Double-click on the "Properties" node for your project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Change the text in the "Assembly name" textbox.

Comment: is it essential to change the name of the assembly if I'm changing the name of the project. the basic aim of renaming the project is to make others understand what it does. When I started coding it I wasnt very sure if it would serve the purpose so the name I used for the project was auto generated.

Comment: @olive: It's not "essential", but I would recommend it. In almost all cases, it's best to name your project the same thing as the assembly that it generates when you compile it. It just makes things much easier to sort out later.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

- Right click the project and select `Rename`
- Select and press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Click-wait-click

To change the name of the output assembly you need to right click and select `Properties`. Change `Assembly Name` in the `Application` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click the project and choose rename.